# Calling OCaml from Qt/C++ : undefined reference

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, ocaml

Machine / system / compiler : Surface Pro 3 / Ubuntu 16.04 64bits on VMWare / GCC 5.4.0

I need to call OCaml code from my Qt application.
I built OCaml 4.05 from sources, following the instructions in the install.doc, but without compiling the native-code compiler.

Now, in Qt, I have the following code :

**.pro**

```
QT       += core gui

TARGET = Editor
TEMPLATE = app

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/ocaml/ -lcamlrun
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/ocaml
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/ocaml
unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../../../../../../../usr/local/lib/ocaml/libcamlrun.a

LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -ldl

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h \

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
extern "C" {
    #include "caml/mlvalues.h"
    #include "caml/callback.h"
}

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    ...
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

char* callCaml(int arg)
{
    static value* closure = nullptr;
    if (!closure)
        closure = caml_named_value("fct");
    return String_val( caml_callback(*closure, Val_int(arg)) );
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
    ,ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    caml_main((char**)(&("a.o")));
    msgBox.setText(callCaml(7));
    msgBox.show();
}
```

**OCaml code**

```
let fct = string_of_int;;

let () = Callback.register "fct" fct;;
```

Compiled with the command

```
ocamlc -output-obj -o a.o caml.ml
```

it gives me a warning :

```
a.c: In function ‘caml_startup_exn’:
a.c:2738:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 
‘caml_startup_code_exn’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
return caml_startup_code_exn(caml_code, sizeof(caml_code),
       ^
```

Now, when I compile my project with Qt, I get some errors

```
/.../usr/local/lib/ocaml//libcamlrun.a(startup.o): In function `caml_main':
startup.c:(.text+0x6ab): undefined reference to `caml_names_of_builtin_cprim'
startup.c:(.text+0x6cf): undefined reference to `caml_names_of_builtin_cprim'
/.../usr/local/lib/ocaml//libcamlrun.a(dynlink.o): In function `caml_build_primitive_table':
dynlink.c:(.text+0x223): undefined reference to `caml_names_of_builtin_cprim'
dynlink.c:(.text+0x242): undefined reference to `caml_names_of_builtin_cprim'
dynlink.c:(.text+0x262): undefined reference to `caml_builtin_cprim'
/.../usr/local/lib/ocaml//libcamlrun.a(dynlink.o): In function `caml_build_primitive_table_builtin':
dynlink.c:(.text+0x3b3): undefined reference to `caml_builtin_cprim'
dynlink.c:(.text+0x3d4): undefined reference to `caml_builtin_cprim'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I clarify that I'm new to linux and Qt.
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you did wrong. While unlikely maybe because you didn't build a native compiler something is missing. Anyway, using the ocaml provided by ubuntu I can not reproduce your problem.

So I suggest running "apt-get install ocaml" and using that to compiler your source.